# Why my php script outputs incorrect symbols instead russian letters from sqlite3?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, sqlite

I'm trying to work with sqlite db from php 5.3 using sqlite3.exe on my windows computer.
when I am executing following code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$db = new SQLite3('C:/PHP5/extras/db.sqlite');
$result = $db->query('select * from comp;');
$resx = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
while ($resx != false){
    print_r($resx); echo "<br/>";
    $resx = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
};
```

It outputs �� symbols if text in Russian. But in sqlite CLI I see the letters 'АБ'.
I tried `$db->exec('PRAGMA encoding = "utf-8";');` but it isn't help. What should I do to see the russian text from DB?

Comment: Well what encoding does your terminal use when it displays the correct output of the sqlite CLI? That would also be the correct encoding for the browser. I don't think sqlite would convert different charsets on the fly.

Comment: UTF-8 characters do not work correctly in the Windows console. Use any other tool to view SQLite files.

Comment: okay, I find the way to solve this problem. My cmd.exe uses ibm866 codepage, and dbengine of sqlite stores inserted text as ibm866. When I used sqlitebrowser and see binary values stored at certain fields I see 80 81, so they match "АБ" in ibm866.

Comment: And there is no way to see text in cp866 in chrome. However, if I run `chcp 1251` in my cmd, inserts works great and selects in php too, but if I use `chcp 65001` which refer to utf-8, my insert fails. sqlite.exe simple crashing without any word.